# NodeJS - Redis connection events

Tags: node.js, events, redis, database-connection

My aim is as follows:

- Connect to a Redis instance **once** only at the start of the program.
- `module.exports` the connection method so that a file can `require`s this object and initiate connection. The resulting client is then 'passed' over to other modules.
- IF the connection broke, then a corresponding exception will be raised and handled accordingly.

I can get the first two to work. But, I am not sure, how to handle other events of Redis *elsewhere* in my project source.

Example:

`connect-once.js` I am connecting with `async` so that the calling function can `await` for connection completion.

```js
const redis = require('redis')
//
async function clientOperations(options) {
    let connObject = {}
    let redisClient = redis.createClient(options)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        redisClient.on('error', (err) => {
            connObject = {
                cacheClient: {},
                connected: false
            }
            reject(connObject)
        })
        //
        redisClient.on('connect', () => {
            connObject = {
                cacheClient: redisClient,
                connected: true
            }
            resolve(connObject)
        })
    })
}
//
async function connect(options) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            let p = await clientOperations(options)
            resolve(p)
        } catch(e) {
            reject(e)
        }
    })
}
//
module.exports = { connect }
```

`init.js`

```js
const cache = require('connect-once')
let cacheClient = await cache.connect()
//
const bizlogic = require('some-biz-logic')
await bizlogic.addcustomer({cacheClient : cacheClient, payload : express.req.payload})
```

In the above snippet, what happens when Redis connection drops while in `bizlogic.addcustomer`? Maybe, I am thinking too 'procedural programming'. I am curious to know how do I connect once, share the connection with rest of the project and handling any connection errors while using that connection somewhere in the project.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest use ioredis over redis
    `npm i ioredis`
https://github.com/luin/ioredis#auto-reconnect

By default, ioredis will try to reconnect when the connection to Redis is lost except when the connection is closed 
manually by redis.disconnect() or redis.quit().

Its very flexible to control how long to wait to reconnect after disconnection using the retryStrategy option:

```
var redis = new Redis({
  // This is the default value of `retryStrategy`
  retryStrategy: function(times) {
    var delay = Math.min(times * 50, 2000);
    return delay;
  }
});
```

Example `connect-once.js`

```
const Redis = require('ioredis');

let connObject;

//
async function clientOperations(options) {
    if (connObject && connObject.connected) {
        return connObject;
    }
    let redisClient = Redis({
        host: options.host,
        port: options.port,
        password: options.password,
        lazyConnect: true,
    });
    await redisClient.connect();
    connObject = {
        cacheClinet: redisClient,
        connected: true
    }
    return connObject;
}

//
async function connect(options) {
    return clientOperations(options);
}
//
module.exports = { connect }
```

Comment: Automatic reconnection happens with `redis` package also. Infact, it emits events for the same too.

Comment: ioredis : A delightful, performance-focused and full-featured Redis client. Supports Cluster, Sentinel, Pipelining and Lua Scripting (https://redis.io/clients#nodejs) . connObject is shared. By default, all pending commands will be flushed with an error every 20 retry attempts. That makes sure commands won't wait forever when the connection is down. You can change this behavior by setting maxRetriesPerRequest.

Comment: I think this may be outdated or not the same with how typescript would work.  Still useful though thank you.